# Struts tag inside display tag

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I am getting error when i refer display tag reference from struts tag.

```
<display:table name="lstEntities" uid="prty">
        <display:column property="propertyType.propertyTypeName"
            titleKey="common.propertytype" />
        <display:column property="propertyName" titleKey="common.property" />
        <display:column titleKey="common.concern" >
        <s:select list="${prty.propertyConcern}" listKey="prtyCrnId" listValue="concern.concernText"></s:select>
        </display:column>
    </display:table>
```

Error:

```
Custom tag attribute list cannot be runtime expression. value: "[${prty.propertyConcern}]"
```

Please help me. how to resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such expressions were allowed in earlier releases of Struts2, but were turned off after struts 2.0.10 to resolve [a security issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2107).

You should be able to access the "prty" object in struts tags using this alternative syntax:

```
<s:select list="#attr.prty.propertyConcern" listKey="prtyCrnId" listValue="concern.concernText"></s:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying `fieldValue="#attr.resultTable1.id"` to `fieldValue="%{#attr.resultTable1.id}"` resolved my problem.

i.e.:

```
<display:table name="libraryList" requestURI="showCopyTravelType.action" sort="external"
defaultsort="1" pagesize="10" uid="resultTable1" partialList="true" size="totalRecordCount">
<display:column title="Select">
<s:checkbox id="copiedFlag" name="copiedFlag" fieldValue="%{#attr.resultTable1.id}" />
</display:column>
<display:column property="code"/>
<display:column property="name"  />
<display:column property="description"  />
<display:footer>
<s:submit action="copyTravelType" />
<s:submit action="searchTravelType"/>
</display:footer>
</display:table>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<s:select list="#attr.prty.propertyConcern" listKey="prtyCrnId" listValue="concern.concernText"></s:select>
```

If we want a list then the parameter should passed like:

```
list="%{#attr.prty.propertyConcern}"
```